# Woocommerce check if coupon already applied?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

So on the `checkout` page, how can i tell if a coupon has previously been applied from the `cart` page? I can check this condition via jquery but the doesnt function how i want because that doesnt happen until the DOM has already loaded. I want the `form-checkout.php` page to check for the coupon before its sent to the user, so i can either hide or show `<p    class="woocommerce-info">Have a coupon? <a href="#" class="showcoupon">Click here to enter your code</a></p>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code. This will hide 'Coupon form' on checkout page, if any coupon is already applied from cart

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled', 'woocommerce_coupons_enabled_checkout' );

function woocommerce_coupons_enabled_checkout( $coupons_enabled ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( ! empty( $woocommerce->cart->applied_coupons ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $coupons_enabled;
}
```

Hope this will be helpful

Comment: Im assuming that this code goes into the `form-checkout.php` page? If you its not working for me

Comment: Where did you placed this code in form-checkout.php? When I placed this code just below "global $woocommerce;" in the same file, it worked for me

Comment: I guess i was placing it in the wrong place...working as designed with your placement suggestions

Comment: Great! Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: The file form-checkout.php either doesn't exist anymore in the updated WooCommerce plug-in, or it doesn't exist when WooCommerce Checkout Manager is installed (I'm pretty confident it's for the former, rather than latter, reason).

How can I implement this now?

Comment: `form-checkout.php` does exists in latest WooCommerce i.e. version 2.2.8. It is located at `/woocommerce/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php`

Comment: this is supposed to go into the functions.php file. the add_filter causes it to be called at the proper place.